# PHP - multiple search queries (from form) in array (from textfile).. or something

Tags: php, file, search

Didn't know exactly what to call this.. Anyways:

I have a text-file consisting of:

```
something;something2;something3;something4\n
```

I use a regular html-form for userinput.
Userinput = $search.
I send this to my search-function:

```
function search($search) {
$lin = file('text.txt');
$lines = array_map('strtolower', $lin);
$found = false;
foreach($lines as $line) {
if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
$found = true;
$line = explode(";",$line);
$line[1] = ucwords($line[1]);
$line[2] = ucwords($line[2]);
$line[3] = strtoupper($line[3]);
echo "$hit[0] $hit[1] etc";
}
}
if(!$found) {
echo "No matches";
}
}
```

This works fine if the user only inputs one words. Let's say the content of the file is:
foo;bar;chuck;hank;

I would like the user to be able to search "foo chuck" and still get a result. Even if only one word match, the line should be echoed (ex "foo carl" still outputs the entire line).

But then again, if there is a "foo;bar" and a "foo;carl", I don't want foo bar to show if the user searches for "foo carl"..

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to put your string into an array, then loop over the array and check for a hit .... or better yet, use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$string='something;something2;something3;something4';
$array=explode(';',$string);
if(in_array('test',$array) || in_array('othertest',$array) || in_array('thirdval',$array)){
    ;//there's a match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the user input, split it into words, normalize them in the same manner as you normalize the file contents and put them into an array `$input`.

Then, for each row in the file contents follow the exact same procedure again ending up with an array `$line`.

Based on your description a search hit occurs when all the words inside `$input` are also present inside `$line`, which could be expressed as:

```
$hit = count(array_intersect($input, $line)) == count($input);
```

Don't forget to "trim" `$input` and `$line` using `array_unique` to cover the case where a search term appears more than once.

Example code:

```
function search($search) {
  // break input into words and normalize
  // explode() is maybe not going to cut it in production, but it's OK here
  $search = array_unique(explode(' ', strtolower($search)));
  $terms = count($search);

  $lines = file('text.txt');
  $found = false;
  foreach($lines as $line) {
    // same treatment as for input
    $line = array_unique(explode(' ', strtolower($line)));

    if(count(array_intersect($search, $line)) == $terms) {
      $found = true;
      $line = explode(";",$line);
      $line[1] = ucwords($line[1]);
      $line[2] = ucwords($line[2]);
      $line[3] = strtoupper($line[3]);
      echo "$hit[0] $hit[1] etc";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I'm following... The ucwords etc are purely for outputs. I want line[1] to uppercase first words and the line[3] to be all in upper. As far as I know it has nothing to do with the search itself :)

Comment: @user1717380: My bad, misread the code. I edited the answer and added an example.

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with large fie using `file` might not be the best approach because Reads entire file into an array and putting it into memory. Your file also looks like CSV so you can use `fgetcsv` all you need to change is the delimiter

Try

```
$file = "large_file.txt";
$search = "something2";
var_dump(search($file, $search));
```

Other Usage

```
search($file, $search,true); // Multiple Result
search($file, $search,true,","); // File has , has delimiter Instead of ;
```

Function

```
function search($file, $search, $multiple = false, $delimiter = ";") {
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $list = array();
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, $delimiter)) !== FALSE ) {
        if (in_array($search, $data)) {
            if ($multiple)
                $list[] = $data;
            else
                return $data;
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
    return $list;
}
```