# Searching a CSV With PHP

Tags: php, search, csv, lookup

I have a large CSV file. The first column contains the name of a processor. The second, the processor's benchmark score. EG:

> Intel Pentium Dual T3400 @ 2.16GHz,1322

Using a PHP script, I would like to search the first column for a string (EG. Pentium Dual T3400), and (assuming that there is only one result per search, else return an error message) create a variable containing the value of the second column.

I don't know if this will help, but I was sort of hoping it would look a little like this:

```
$cpuscore = csvsearch(CSV_file,query_string,column#_to_search,column#_to_return)
```

Where $cpuscore would contain the score of the processor name that matches the search query.

Feel free to suggest something that would produce similar results. I have MySQL, but I don't have the permissions to import tables from CSV.

Comment: [`fgetscsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) is the place to start

Comment: This  may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12921943/1226894

Comment: You'd have to use fgetcsv() in a loop and search each returned row for your target data.  the problem with this approach is it's slow and directly dependant on the size of your CSV file.  If at all possible you're much better off using some sort of database, they have far more sophisticated text searching and indexing facilities and the result will be a much faster search

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function fgetcsv(), http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php to traverse the csv file row by row. For instance:

```
$ch = fopen($path_to_file, "r");
$found = '';

/* If your csv file's first row contains Column Description you can use this to remove the first row in the while */
$header_row = fgetcsv($ch);

/* This will loop through all the rows until it reaches the end */
while(($row = fgetcsv($ch)) !== FALSE) {

    /* $row is an array of columns from that row starting at 0 */
    $first_column = $row[0];

    /* Here you can do your search */
    /* If found $found = $row[1]; */
    /* Now $found will contain the 2nd column value (if found) */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to iterate through each line of a csv file and find the words i'm looking for, and compile a result from there. Here's something to get you started:

```
     <?php
   $query = "Intel Core i7 3600M"     
   $file = file('db.csv');    
       foreach($file as $value) { 
         if(stristr($value,$query)){
            $items = explode(",", $value); echo $items[1];
              }; 
         };
    ?>
```

Comment: Because his CSV file is quite large, `file()` could eat a lot of memory. `fopen` would be better for this.

Comment: I used this. Thanks.
If you were wondering, below is my finished code. This way works regardless of case, and always returns the first result.
$query = "Intel Core i7 3600M"
$file=file('db.csv');
foreach($file as $value){
    if(stristr($value,$query)){
 $items = explode(",", $value);
 echo $items[1];
 };
};