# Caching SQL Lookups & Retrieving Data

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I'm trying to setup caching of postcode lookups, which adds the resulting lookup to a text file using the following;

```
file_put_contents($cache_file, $postcode."\t".$result."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

I'd like to be able to check this file before running a query, which i have done using this:

```
if( strpos(file_get_contents($cache_file),$postcode) !== false) {
  // Run function
}
```

What I'd like to do, is search for the $postcode with in the text file (as above) and return the data one tab over ($result).

Firstly, is this possible?

Secondly, is this is even a good way to cache SQL lookups?

Comment: Seems this is easier using CSV... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922772/searching-a-csv-with-php

Answer (score 1):

1) yes it's possible - the easiest way would be storing the lookup data in an `array` and write/read it from a file with `serialze` / `unserialze`

```
$lookup_codes = array(
    '10101' => 'data postcode 1 ...',
    '10102' => 'data postcode 2 ...',
    // ...
);

file_put_contents($cache_file, serialize($lookup_codes));
$lookup_codes = unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));

$postcode = '10101';
if(array_key_exists($postcode, $lookup_codes)){
 // ... is available
}
```

2) is the far more interesting question. It **really** depends on your data, the structure, the amount etc.

In my opinion, caching add more complexity to your application, and so if possible avoid it :-)

You could try to:

- Optimizing your SQL query or database structure to speed it up for requesting postcode data.
  Normally Databases are quite fast - and therefore made for such use-cases

  I'm not sure which db you are running, but for MySQL look into [Select Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html). Or as another keyword you can search for `INDEX` which boost queries quite heavy
- `file_get_contents` is really fast, but when you are changing the file often maybe look into other ways of caching, like [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) for storing it In-Memory

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I did implement a form of caching, but the speed improvement was marginal, so perhaps not worth it in this instance. Very much appreciate you taking the time to reply! Thanks!